# UIButton touchable area is increased but not reflecting in iphone whether it is fine in simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

My problem is that, I want to increase the touchable area of `UIButton` with an `image`. The `image` size is smaller that of `UIButton`.

I am able to achieve this in `simulator` but not in device (`iPhone`).

Thanks in advance...

Comment: show your code here ..

Comment: Thanks Vaibhav,  I did not code, i have set this from storyboard

Comment: okay so probably the problem is in your ui constraints you have set ..please approve edit first so other can understand your ques properly.

Answer (score 2):

One easier way is to have the button on the size that you want to be clickable and then change the size of the image inside that button.

`self.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5);`

This will create a "padding" of 5px for each side.

Or use the storyboard if you have your button there.

Comment: Hi Andre Cytryn, thanks for youe help, i have done same things and have set imageEdgeInsets from storyboard but its not working in iphone whether it works in simulator

Comment: @AnkitKr.Vishwakarma imageEdgeInsets workd only if the image is set as the button-image instead of button-background-image

Answer (score 2):

Just write a extension of UIControl like below:

```
@interface UIControl (HitTestEdge)
@property (nonatomic, assign) UIEdgeInsets hitTestEdgeInsets;
@end


@implementation UIControl (HitTestEdge)
@dynamic hitTestEdgeInsets;

static const NSString *UIControlTouchEdgeKey = @"HitTestEdgeInsets";

-(void)setHitTestEdgeInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)hitTestEdgeInsets
{
    NSValue *value = [NSValue value:&hitTestEdgeInsets withObjCType:@encode(UIEdgeInsets)];
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &UIControlTouchEdgeKey, value, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

-(UIEdgeInsets)hitTestEdgeInsets
{
    NSValue *value = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &UIControlTouchEdgeKey);
    if(value) {
        UIEdgeInsets edgeInsets; [value getValue:&edgeInsets]; return edgeInsets;
    }else {
        return UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    }
}

- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if(UIEdgeInsetsEqualToEdgeInsets(self.hitTestEdgeInsets, UIEdgeInsetsZero) ||       !self.enabled || self.hidden) {
        return [super pointInside:point withEvent:event];
    }

    CGRect relativeFrame = self.bounds;
    CGRect hitFrame = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(relativeFrame, self.hitTestEdgeInsets);

    return CGRectContainsPoint(hitFrame, point);
}
@end
```

Set the `hitTestEdgeInsets` property to extend the button click area.

**Example:**

```
btn.hitTestEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-10, -10, -10, -10)
```

and the button will extend it's click boundary with 10px.